# Magento 1.7.0.2: Display default qty in the drop-down bundled product options

Tags: magento

This is the code from file **"select.phtml"**: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml

What code do i need to insert so that i can display the default qty next to the product name in the drop-down bundled product options

**Or at least how can i get the default qty of the options based on product ID?**

```
<?php $_option      = $this->getOption(); ?>
<?php $_selections  = $_option->getSelections(); ?>
<?php $_default     = $_option->getDefaultSelection(); ?>
<?php list($_defaultQty, $_canChangeQty) = $this->_getDefaultValues(); ?>

<dt>
    <label<?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle()) ?><?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?></label>
</dt>

<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
         <?php if ($this->_showSingle()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selections[0]) ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="bundle_option[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_selections[0]->getSelectionId() ?>"/>
          <?php else:?>

        <select onchange="bundle.changeSelection(this)" id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" name="bundle_option[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" class="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?><?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo ' required-entry' ?> bundle-option-select change-container-classname">

            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Choose a selection...') ?></option>

        <?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection): ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>"<?php if ($this->_isSelected($_selection)) echo ' selected="selected"' ?><?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?>><?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, false) ?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php endif; ?>


    <span class="qty-holder" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px;">

        <label for="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?>&nbsp;</label><input onkeyup="bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)" onblur="bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)" <?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?> id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input" class="input-text qty<?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' qty-disabled' ?>" type="text" name="bundle_option_qty[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_defaultQty ?>" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);"/>

    </span>
 </div>

</dd>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php $_option      = $this->getOption(); ?>
<?php $_selections  = $_option->getSelections(); ?>
<?php $_default     = $_option->getDefaultSelection(); ?>
<?php list($_defaultQty, $_canChangeQty) = $this->_getDefaultValues(); ?>

<dt>
    <label<?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle()) ?><?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?></label>
</dt>

<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
         <?php if ($this->_showSingle()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selections[0]) ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="bundle_option[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_selections[0]->getSelectionId() ?>"/>
          <?php else:?>

        <select onchange="bundle.changeSelection(this)" id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" name="bundle_option[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" class="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?><?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo ' required-entry' ?> bundle-option-select change-container-classname">

            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Choose a selection...') ?></option>

        <?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection): ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>"<?php if ($this->_isSelected($_selection)) echo ' selected="selected"' ?><?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?>><?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, false) ?> (Default Qty: <?php echo $_selection->getSelectionQty() ?>)</option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php endif; ?>


    <span class="qty-holder" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px;">

        <label for="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?>&nbsp;</label><input onkeyup="bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)" onblur="bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)" <?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?> id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input" class="input-text qty<?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' qty-disabled' ?>" type="text" name="bundle_option_qty[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_defaultQty ?>" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);"/>

    </span>
 </div>

</dd>
```

Use above code to show the default qty in dropdown. I have added only below code inside the foreach loop

```
(Default Qty: <?php echo $_selection->getSelectionQty() ?>)
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot monojit, this is exactly what i wanted. I appreciate very much your input :)

Comment: I know that this is off topic, but do you know how can i get the original product ID of selected option in the same loop? I can get an ID by using this `<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>` but this is not the original ID of the selected product. Do you have any ideas or suggestions how can i get it?

Comment: Yes u can by using <?php echo $_selection->getId() ?>

Comment: Thank you again, you are my hero today